# How do $\cos\theta= -1$ and $\sin\theta= 0$ imply that $\theta= \pi$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}5 + 4\cos(\theta) \\ 1 + 4 \sin(\theta)\end{bmatrix} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}\\[4pt]
\implies \quad \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta)\end{bmatrix} 
&= \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ \phantom{-}0\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}\\[4pt]
\implies \quad \theta &= \pi \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

How did they conclude that $\theta$ is equal to $\pi$? I don't understand the step from $(2)$ to $(3)$.

Comment: $\cos \theta=-1 \implies \theta = \arccos(-1) = \pi$

Comment: $\theta = (2n+1){\pi}$

Comment: Try just plotting.

Comment: They concluded incorrectly; all that can be inferred is that $\theta = (2k+1)\pi$ for some integer $k$. If there was an assumption that you didn't mention here, like $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$, then the conclusion is valid, for reasons expressed in the answers.

Comment: What about $\theta = -\pi$ that is a valid solution also. Point being, there is a range assumption for $\theta$ which is missing here.Anyway, for problems like this use the trigonometric circle, noting that $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ are the coordinate of a point on the circle.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have $( \cos \theta, \sin \theta) = (-1,0)$, you must have
$$
\begin{cases}\cos \theta = -1 \\ \sin \theta = 0\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}\cos \theta = -1 \\ \theta = k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases} (-1)^k = -1 \\ \theta = k \pi\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases} k = 2n+1 \\ \theta = (2n+1)\pi, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}\end{cases}
$$

If you are assuming that $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi[$, the only solution is in fact $\theta = \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos\theta=-1$ for odd multiplies of $\pi$; $\sin\theta=0$ is a weaker condition, valid for all multiples of $\pi$. For $\theta\in[0,\,2\pi)$, the only solution is $\pi$.